# Chrome user agent stylesheet overwriting my site style

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, google-chrome, web

I have the following CSS that styles the link on one of my pages:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

However, when I load it, they appear blue in Chrome and white in Firefox. The Chrome dev tools reveal that my style supposedly overwrites the user agent stylesheet:

[image]

Why is it not showing correctly? I tried setting the charset at the top of my stylesheet:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font: 11px "Lucida Grande", Arial, Sans-serif;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=email], input[type=password] {
    display: block;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ACE;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 203px;
}
```

But it didn't help. My stylesheet is linked in the head with:

```
<link href="/assets/global.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css">
```

And the html code for the links:

```
<a href="/users/sign_in">Sign in</a>
<a href="/users/password/new">Forgot your password?</a>
<a href="/users/auth/facebook">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

This is what they look like in Chrome (13.0.782) - incorrect:

[image]

This is what they look like in Firefox - correct:

[image]

It looks like the user agent stylesheet is overwriting my style. Why?

Comment: It is not. Describe your problem more specific. Which style does not apply? What is html code of incorrect styled elements.

Comment: The links are supposed to appear white in Chrome. They appear correctly in Firefox.

Comment: Works perfect on my desktop - chrome 13.0.782.220 m. And according to http://i.stack.imgur.com/FlIjd.jpg color of selected link is white.

Comment: Correct, it is supposed to be white, but shows up as blue, as pictured in http://i.stack.imgur.com/qlHa0.jpg on my Chrome instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vonkly helped identify the issue. I went digging through all my stylesheets and I found a typo, sort of, in one of them - it was missing the parent element when defining the link style for the header, so instead of

```
header a:link, header a:visited {
...
}
```

I had

```
header a:link, a:visited {
...
}
```

so it was overriding the style I defined for the links in the body. I must have missed it while reviewing my stylesheets the first time around.

Thanks for your comments, everybody!

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why but I add this `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` 
before `<html>` and it solved

Comment: That's super obsolete at this point. Use `<!doctype html>` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the `<html>` tag.

Comment: This is worked. My document was missing the doctype, and I came here with the diagnoses, that the user agent stylesheet is overwriting my css.

Answer (score 2):

I was having same kind of problem, i my case my some classes are forcefully settled to display : none

After 30/40 min i looked up on browser extensions , and found out all these was happening due to **AD Blocker**.

so if any above solution does'nt work for you, then try this as well once if you have this kind of browser extension.

Answer (score 1):

The user agent stylesheet only kicks in if your css neglects to define a property for a tag.  Consider that you might have a typo in your css style.

Chances are that, if you put the tag declaration at the beginning of the css file and it works, that you have an error in your css.

Try running your css thru [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/)

I had this persistent problem and discovered a mistake in my css.

Answer (score 1):

Force your margin before the browser sets it for you

```css
body {
    margin: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the general css anchor style `a`:

```
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also, you don't need to set the charset in your css file. I would remove that.

The charset *should* be set in the HTTP header, which is where it belongs.

Comment: Are the css groups listed above the only elements in your stylesheet? Are you perhaps using another stylesheet, or have the anchor color defined in the wrapping container with `!important`?

Comment: Also, try removing the de-cache trick (the `?body=1`). I doubt that's your error - it's more likely something to do with your anchor tags being defined with the `!important` rule applied. I have been unable to recreate this issue on any of my computers in Chrome.