# Single line (one or two words) overflowing outide a div

Tags: css, html, xhtml, overflow

I am brand new to CSS so please forgive me if this is a foolish problem.

I have created a footer with 3 embedded div's of 33.33% of the width inside of it. For some reason the text that I am putting into each div is half in and half out of the bottom of the div. This is driving me insane. Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Here is my XHTML:

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 strict//EN" "http://www.3org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

 <meta http-equiv="content-type"
 content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />

<title>www.BLeeOBS.com</title>

<link rel = "stylesheet"
 type = "text/css"
 href = "twoCol.css" />

</head>

<body background="images/brick.jpg">

<div id="body">

<div id="head">
 <h1>B. Lee Oil Burner Service</h1>
</div>

<div id="head_right">
 <h1></h1>
</div>

<div id="left">
 <h2></h2>
</div>

<div id="right">
 <h2></h2>
</div>

<div id="footer">

  <div id="footer1">
  <h3>Fully Insured</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="footer2">
  <h3>HIC# PA088378</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="footer3">
  <h3>©2013</h3>
  </div>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#body {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-image: url("images/bggradient.jpg");
 text-align: center;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 width: 768px;
 height: 1024px;
}
#head {
 background-image: url("images/horizontalpipe.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 float: left;
 height: 90px;
 width: 678px;
}
 #head_right {
 background-image: url("images/elbow.png");
 float: left;
 width: 90px;
 height:90px;
}
#left {
 float: left;
 height: 904px;
 width: 678px;
}
#right {
 background-image: url("images/verticalpipe.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 float: left;
 width: 90px;
 height: 904px;
}
#footer {
 background-color: gray;
 color: white;
 height: 30px;
 width: 768px;
 clear: both;
}
#footer1 {
 height: 30px;
 float: left;
 width: 33.33%;
}
#footer2 {
 height: 20px;
 float: left;
 width: 33.33%;
}
#footer3 {
height: 20px;
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
}
```

my page can be viewed here to see what's happening:
http://www.bleeobs.com/bricksswf.html

the white text should be entirely in the grey box (my div) but as you can see it is halfway out.

Also, I'd like to bring the text "B. Lee Oil Burner Service" a little bit higher in the header. Setting the padding doesn't seem to help at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `reset.css` that will overwrite all the default css that applies by browser

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but the margins are being set by "user agent stylesheet" I see here:

[image: inspector]

THe immediate fix is setting

```
h3 { margin: 0 }
```

or however you want it. According to this [Chrome user agent stylesheet overwriting my site style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466404/chrome-user-agent-stylesheet-overwriting-my-site-style) you might want to look into the correct fix. It may be having the desired  at the top of your document (perhaps  for html 5)or it might be broken css somewhere.

edit: Looks like Adrift might be correct about the default browser styles needing to be reset. You can use a reset.css like he's suggesting.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick responses. Seems to be working properly now.